# Turning desert map green in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency, images, photo-editing

I have only started using photoshop yesterday, so I have virtually no experience and no idea what I’m doing.

What I want to do is:

1- overlay a map of river paths on top of the desert map, and change the color and opacity of some of these rivers.

2- change the colors of the desert to green (realistic looking green land). Also, I want to preserve the original features of the land such as mountains, canyons, valleys, etc)

[image]

Comment: Photoshop is not really suitable software for map making.  It's a raster image editor, a photo editor.  There's actual cartography software for this kind of thing, or if you don't want to go down that route, something like a vector image editor might be usable.

Comment: Or maybe posting an image of your specific case.

Comment: I just did. I hope this clarifies things

Comment: 1. You can use a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer to change the colour of the river paths.
2. You can use a Levels adjustment layer to adjust the brightness and contrast of the image.
3. You can use a Curves adjustment layer to fine-tune the colours and tones of the image.
4. You can use a Gradient Map adjustment layer to create a more realistic-looking green desert.

Comment: Yeah I tried all these and got a somewhat satisfying result.